# Cucumber lambdas for other languages

Tags: java, java-8, cucumber

The classic way of step definition pre-Java 8 allows you to use the actual keywords of other languages for the annotations.

```
@前提("totally new stuff")
public void totallyNewStuff() {
    System.out.println("hello world")
}
```

What would be the equivalent of this as a Java 8 lambda?

I am assuming that the Cucumber test would work if I were to simply write the step definitions in English like so:

```
Given("totally new stuff",() -> System.out.println("hello world"));
```

But that would defeat the purpose of localized Gherkin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Japanese you implement the `Ja` interface instead of the `En` interface. But it's worth nothing that using `前提` or `Given` makes no functional difference. Steps are matched regardless of keyword.

```
import io.cucumber.java8.Ja;

public class RpnCalculatorSteps implements Ja {
    private RpnCalculator calc;

    public RpnCalculatorSteps() {

        前提("totally new stuff", () -> {

        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a note that the package name is actually `cucumber.api.java8.ja`. `io.cucumber.java8` is for the maven package (`io.cucumber.cucumber-java8` to be precise). Thanks though!

Comment: You may want to consider upgrading your cucumber. We're almost on v5. :D

Comment: what do you mean? I'm just using maven latest. kinda new to cucumber to be honest?

Comment: You should be using the dependencies from the `io.cucumber` groupId.

Comment: My goodness, I just realised you're the project maintainer! Thanks for responding to my questions. I'm using v4.7.2 because that's the latest on maven central and my IDE autocomplete points me to `cucumber.api.java8.ja`. I'm assuming `io.cucumber` comes into effect in a snapshot release?

Comment: `io.cucumber.java8.Ja` is available in v4.7.2. But looks like IDEA only supports annotations and not lambdas in `io.cucumber`. That might be your problem.